# Page not found in django project

Tags: python, django

in my django project,when i access localhost:8000 it say:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
```

the urls.py is:

```
^$/
hello/$
now/$
^add/$
todolist/$
userlist/$
admin/
^currenturl/$
task/addUI/$
task/addUI/taskadd/$
```

the django version is 1.3.3
what's problems ,thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a typo in your first route, it should be `^/$`

Answer (score 1):

Actually there is no need of a last slash in regex if 'APPEND_SLASH' is True.

```
    url(r'^$', ...)
```

Pls. refer to [Djanobook ch. 3](http://djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter03/)    with this: "If you’re the type of person who likes all URLs to end with slashes (which is the preference of Django’s developers), all you’ll need to do is add a trailing slash to each URLpattern and leave APPEND_SLASH set to True. If you prefer your URLs not to have trailing slashes, or if you want to decide it on a per-URL basis, set APPEND_SLASH to False and put trailing slashes in your URLpatterns as you see fit."